# Display time duration as hourly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a program to calculate downtime so i want it to start calculating from the starting point to the END where downtime is finish.
e.g (0 to 5minutes ,49minutes, 1hr : 36minutes) 
What methods i can try to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the time now (in milliseconds) you can call `Date.now()`. Store this somewhere and call the function again at the end. Subtract the start from the end and you get the total time elapsed, in milliseconds. After that, the rest is just simple math to transform milliseconds to seconds, minutes, hours and so forth.

Comment: i have something like this <div id="timeInfo"> 00:00 </div> and i want it like when a movie is playing

Comment: @C_Major ... can you provide your code snippet and explain in detail what exactly you want. This will be helpful in helping you out in this. Like What exactly you mean by "I want it like when a movie is playing"? Do you need it to be continuously increasing every second or millisecond?